# Three.js: not able to punch(cut) line shape by using THREE.ExtrudeGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, geometry, drawing

Hello guys I am new to Three.js

I want to punch(cut) some shapes in the plain board by using THREE.ExtrudeGeometry.

Here is my code in snippet.

```js
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    camera.position.z = 10;
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 2, 100);
    light.position.z = 10;
    scene.add(light);
    
    let boardHeight = 100;
    let boardWidth = 100;
    
    const boardShape = new THREE.Shape();
    boardShape.moveTo(0, 0);
    boardShape.lineTo(0, boardHeight);
    boardShape.lineTo(boardWidth, boardHeight);
    boardShape.lineTo(boardWidth, 0);
    boardShape.lineTo(0, 0);
    
    var hole1 = new THREE.Path();
    hole1.moveTo(20, 20); 
    hole1.lineTo(18, 20);
    boardShape.holes.push(hole1);
    hole1 = new THREE.Path(); 
    hole1.moveTo(50, 50);
    hole1.absarc(30, 50, 20, 0.0000, Math.PI*2, true);
    boardShape.holes.push(hole1);
    hole1 = new THREE.Path(); 
    hole1.moveTo(25, 25); 
    hole1.lineTo(27, 25); 
    boardShape.holes.push(hole1);
    
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x005E99 } );
    
    const extrudeSettings = { depth: 1, bevelEnabled: false, bevelSegments: 1, steps: 1, bevelSize: 1, bevelThickness: 1, UVGenerator: THREE.ExtrudeGeometry.WorldUVGenerator };                 
    
    const geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(boardShape,  extrudeSettings);
    
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    geometry.scale(0.02, 0.02, 0.02);
    cube.position.set(-boardWidth / 2 * 0.02, -boardHeight / 2 * 0.02, 0.02 * 0.5);
    scene.add( cube );
    
    camera.position.z = 5;
    
    var render = function () {
      requestAnimationFrame( render );    
      //cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
      //cube.rotation.y += 0.1;    
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };
    
    render();
    
    // Rotate the mesh based on mouse position
    document.body.onmousemove = function(e){
      //cube.rotation.z = e.pageX / 100;
      //cube.rotation.x = e.pageY / 100;
    }
    
    // Click to toggle wireframe mode
    document.body.onclick = function(e){
      cube.material.wireframe = !cube.material.wireframe;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r124/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/mrdoob/three.js/r124/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Wilt/ThreeCSG/develop/ThreeCSG.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

I have added one circle shape and a two-line shape in the given example.

I can punch hole for circle shape but for line shape it does not work.

I also attached images for current output and expected output

Current Output :

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: Lines don't have width at all.

Comment: @prisoner849 How can I implement this, I required a circle as well as a line with a rounded cap to be extruded on the same plane. Can you help me out with the shared code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to trace a rectangle with rounded corners with the path.
For a two points as ends of the line (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), it's possible to get the 8 vertices corresponding to the rectangle as a path:

```
const getPath = (x1, y1, x2, y2, thickness = 1, radius = 0) => {
    const vector1 = new THREE.Vector2(x1, y1);
    const vector2 = new THREE.Vector2(x2, y2);
    const direction = vector2.clone().sub(vector1).normalize();
    const angle = direction.angle();
    const perpendicularDirection = direction.clone().rotateAround(new THREE.Vector2(0, 0), Math.PI / 2);
    const path = new THREE.Path();
    path.moveTo(...vector2.clone().addScaledVector(perpendicularDirection, thickness - radius).toArray());
    if(radius > 0) {
      path.arc(...direction.clone().multiplyScalar(-radius).toArray(), radius, angle, angle + Math.PI / 2);
    }
    path.lineTo(
      ...vector1.clone()
        .addScaledVector(perpendicularDirection, thickness)
        .addScaledVector(direction, radius)
        .toArray()
    );
    if(radius > 0) {
      path.arc(...perpendicularDirection.clone().multiplyScalar(-radius).toArray(), radius, angle + Math.PI / 2, angle + Math.PI);
    }
    path.lineTo(
      ...vector1.clone()
        .addScaledVector(perpendicularDirection, -(thickness - radius))
        .toArray()
    );
    if(radius > 0) {
      path.arc(...direction.clone().multiplyScalar(radius).toArray(), radius, angle + Math.PI, angle + 1.5 * Math.PI);
    }
    path.lineTo(
      ...vector2.clone()
        .addScaledVector(perpendicularDirection, -(thickness))
        .addScaledVector(direction, -radius)
        .toArray()
    );
    if(radius > 0) {
      path.arc(...perpendicularDirection.clone().multiplyScalar(radius).toArray(), radius, angle + 1.5 * Math.PI, angle + 2 * Math.PI);
    }
    path.lineTo(...vector2.clone().addScaledVector(perpendicularDirection, thickness - radius).toArray());
    return path;
  };
```

and consequently

```
var hole1 = getPath(10, 200, 400, 300, 40, 20);
boardShape.holes.push(hole1);
```